# MySQL database Error Throwing back a #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql

```
<?php

// Basic settings

// You must set these for the server to work

$databaseServer = "fdb7.biz.nf";

$databaseUsername = "TestUsername";

$databasePassword = "TestPassword";

$databaseName = "1620710_castle";
```

It will not reconize the Database server it just shoots back a error

--------------------ERROR------------------------

```
There seems to be an error in your SQL query. The MySQL server error output below, if there is any, may also help you in diagnosing the problem

ERROR: Unknown Punctuation String @ 1
STR: <?
SQL: <?php

// Basic settings
// You must set these for the server to work

$databaseServer = "fdb7.biz.nf";

SQL query:

<?php // Basic settings // You must set these for the server to work $databaseServer = "fdb7.biz.nf";
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near '
>
> // Basic settings // You must set these for the server to work
>
> $database' at line 1

Comment: Um...it looks like you just copied an error message, but you didn't ask a question. Please post the SQL query and give some sort of description of what you're trying to accomplish and what's happening.

Comment: I added on to it hopefully its more discriptive

Comment: You've posted nothing to do with MySQL; you've posted PHP variable declarations: `$databaseServer` and `$databaseUserName` are not part of any SQL dialect, and they aren't part of any MySQL statement. MySQL doesn't "throw back errors" related to declaring variables in PHP.

Comment: Still very unclear. I still don't see an SQL query. How can anyone find a syntax error in a query they can't see? And what do you mean by "it"? When/where/how are you getting this error? Please read this [advice on how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Be sure to follow the link at the bottom to Jon Skeet's blog post [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx). Pay special attention to the "Golden Rule", though I highly advise you to read the entire article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application is submitting a string to the database which is not a SQL statement.

The error message indicates that this text was sent to the database:

```
<?php

// Basic settings
// You must set these for the server to work

$databaseServer = "fdb7.biz.nf";
```

MySQL is choking on the very first character, the less than sign. And none of that is valid SQL.
Something is going horribly wrong in the application that is submitting SQL to the database.

We'd expect to see this #1064 error related to an actual SQL statement, something like:

```
SELECT fee FROM fi WHERE fo = 'fum'
```

But it appears the application is submitting php code to the database, and MySQL isn't able to make heads or tails of it.

Also, the database doesn't "throw" or "shoot back" an error message. It returns a data structure as the result of a library function call, which the client interprets.